# Creating forms for relational data in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webforms, relational-database

I have a form that I need to display for a table that has a relationship with a couple of other tables.  For instance, I have a table "cases" (think, investigator case), that has_one claimant and has_one client.

I would like the form to display the fields to fill out for the case data, client data and claimant data.  Is there an easy way to do this so that when it's submitted, it would be as simple as:

```
case = Case.new(params[:case])
case.save
```

As it would be if I was just submitting and saving a form for only the case data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` method of activerecord.  You will need to craft your form using

```
- form.fields_for :claimant do |claimant_form|
  = claimant_form.text_field :name
```

You can find much more information in [Ryan Daigle's blog post](http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2009/2/1/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-nested-attributes)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's a way where you can just call case.save and it'll work.

To make the form, look into using fields_for. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#M001605

fields_for allows you to add fields that are stored in different POST variables, so if you set up the fields correctly then in your new method you could potentially do something like this:

```
claimant = Claimant.new(params[:claimant])
claimant.save
```

Which isn't terribly more complicated.

Comment: Well, I know that you can fill out an entire relational object like so:

    case = Case.new
    case.claimant = Claimant.new
    # Fill out case and claimant info
    case.save

And it will save the case and claimant stuff in the db properly...  I just wasn't sure if you could do it with the params stuff from a form. I guess not.  

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

See my [complex-form-examples](http://github.com/ryanb/complex-form-examples/tree/master) on creating nested multi-model forms. This has been updated to work with Rails 2.3's `accepts_nested_attributes_for`.

It allows you to nest the associations all under `params[:case]` like you want. When you call `case.save` everything else will be saved too.